# Refreshing an excel pivot table using windows scheduler

Tags: excel, scheduler

I am responsible for updating an Excel spreadsheet which pulls its information from an Access database on a daily basis.  All the data that i need for my excel spreadsheet is available for me and all that i need to do is open the document, provide the password, enable to content and click the refresh button.

The database is very large and updating this during normal working hours causes problems as it slows down other users on the network.  How would i use Windows Scheduler to do this for me outside of working hours?  I'm not sure how to set up my script to follow my steps required.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do something quite similar to this recently, and with the help of this forum I've found something that works for me, and by the sounds of it may work for you too!

I created a notepad file with the following .vbs script

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("Full Path of your file.xlsx")
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save

oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

What this does, it opens the file, refreshes any data connections, then saves the file and exits.

I then put this as a scheduled task to run at an off peak time, so that when the user opens the workbook, it's up to date.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this through the VBA

hit Alt - F11
right click ThisWorkbook and click view code.

the code is as follows:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Workbooks.Open ("location of your workbook"), Password:="whatever your password is"
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub

i save this document and ask the task scheduler to run it at a specific time.